# Kinesis to s3 bucket using Kinesis Connector

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis

I am getting the following error while accessing the s3 bucket from kinesis using the kinesis connector library .
I have used the samples from the following link

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors/tree/master/src/main/samples

```
INFO: Stream twitterStreamNew is ACTIVE
Oct 16, 2015 3:45:00 PM com.yash.KinesisConnectorExecutor setupInputStream
INFO: Starting stream source.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/transform/JsonErrorUnmarshallerV2
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.init(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:387)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:383)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:357)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.(Worker.java:109)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.(Worker.java:94)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.connectors.KinesisConnectorExecutorBase.initialize(KinesisConnectorExecutorBase.java:84)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.connectors.KinesisConnectorExecutorBase.initialize(KinesisConnectorExecutorBase.java:37)
    at com.example.KinesisConnectorExecutor.



    (KinesisConnectorExecutor.java:110)
    at com.example.S3Executor.(S3Executor.java:19)
    at com.example.S3Executor.main(S3Executor.java:34)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:       com.amazonaws.transform.JsonErrorUnmarshallerV2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same error - was simply due to conflicting library versions.

Update your kinesis connector library and aws java sdk to the latest versions in your POM.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.27</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-connectors</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I updated my pom even then I am having the same error.I am using the following dependency in my pom for kineis-s3 connection  1)amazon-kinesis connectors  - 1.2.0  (2)amazon-kinesis-producer - 0.10.1 (3)aws-java-sdk - 1.10.27 (4)aws-java-sdk-dynamodb - 1.10.27 (5)aws-java-sdk-s3 - 1.10.27  (6)com.fasterxml.jackson.core - 2.6.3.Do i need to add any other dependency ??

Comment: Try ordering so that the `aws-java-sdk` is first and `amazon-kinesis-connectors` is second, and run a `maven clean`. You also don't need the dynamodb and s3 libraries as they are included as part of the main package. If you still don't have luck please post your POM. Also just to confirm, this error is when you try to receive messages, not produce them?